# Google API select user, then retrieve email/calendar

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, gmail-api

I have a web app backend which knows which user is using the application. All users have a google account on the client. The client queries the backend for a change in user.

If there is a change in user or if the application has just started. I want to display that persons gmail and calendar.

I currently have it display the inbox headings for only the first user but I'm not sure what steps I would take for it to select the right person. Is there an API for all accounts that are logged into the web browser? That would allow me to search the list returned and then retrieve the emails for the right user.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies but I find your post quite unclear.

For clarification purposes and for the sake of trying to help, if you are referring to multiple login or switching to another account, there's actually an issue discussed in GitHub regarding multiple sign-in, [Multiple sign-in #13](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/13).

According to that thread,

> Multi-login prompting is now supported when initiating the OAuth2 flow through the `gapi.signin` (ie. widget or `gapi.auth.signIn()`) library. Switching accounts should only be a matter of `gapi.auth.signOut()` followed by `gapi.auth.signIn()` again.

You may use [Google Sign-In JavaScript client reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) to know more about JavaScript client methods and attributes to implement Google Sign-In in your web applications.

I hope that helps.